# Can a View hold some data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a View:

```
 CREATE VIEW Lunch
AS
  SELECT 'Beer' AS item
  UNION SELECT 'Olives'
  UNION SELECT 'Bread'
  UNION SELECT 'Salami'
  UNION SELECT 'Calamari'
  UNION SELECT 'Coffee';
GO
```

Then I executed the following query in a different query.

```
SELECT item FROM Lunch
```

This is resulting in the data from the view being returned. There are not any underlying tables to hold data. But still the system is showing records.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't actually hold data, but it can evaluate SQL, which is all you're doing in the definition.

So the following can be evaluated:

```
SELECT 'Beer' AS item
  UNION SELECT 'Olives'
  UNION SELECT 'Bread'
  UNION SELECT 'Salami'
  UNION SELECT 'Calamari'
  UNION SELECT 'Coffee';
```

The same as a view defined with:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
```

### [SQL View Reference:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> A view can be thought of as either a virtual table or a stored query. The data accessible through a view **is not stored in the database as a distinct object**. What is stored in the database is a **SELECT statement**. The result set of the SELECT statement **forms the virtual table** returned by the view. A user can use this virtual table by referencing the view name in Transact-SQL statements the same way a table is referenced.

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand the question.  The view is not "holding data", it is holding a query.  The query statement has constants in it that are turned into a result set that can be used by other queries.

You can think of a query as substituting the text of the query directly into a statement.  So, when you do:

```
select *
from lunch;
```

SQL really processes this as:

```
select *
from ( SELECT 'Beer' AS item
       UNION SELECT 'Olives'
       UNION SELECT 'Bread'
       UNION SELECT 'Salami'
       UNION SELECT 'Calamari'
       UNION SELECT 'Coffee'
     ) t
```

This is a good model of what happens, although it is not quite what really happens.  What really happens is that the view is compiled and the compiled code is inserted into the compiled code for the query.

There is another concept of "materialized views".  These are views where you have indexes and the values are actually stored in the database.  However, this is not an example of a materialized view.

Answer (score 2):

A view is a `Saved Select Statement` in your case view definition does not have any underlying tables, but the select statement itself has hard coded (Constant) values.

Therefore it will always return this data.

Again to be clear it is not storing any data but the Select Statement which happens to return some constant values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the data is shown because is statically included into the query itself.

I don't see anything uncommon here, the view refers to the query that embed the data .